# Emails adicionais não estão sendo enviados - PHPMailer - $mail->addAddress('meuemail@email.com')

Tags: php, email, envio-de-email, phpmailer, smtp

Boa noite.

Estou com um problema um tanto curioso. Possuo um cliente onde fui contratado para dar manutenção em seu site antigo. Como o mesmo não pretende atualizar o site agora, vou me virando no meio daquela bagunça.

Porém, algo estranho me aconteceu: imaginem que dentro desse site eu possuo dois arquivos que tem como função executarem o disparo de e-mail. Portanto eu tenho, por exemplo, os arquivos `envia_email1.php` e `envia_email2.php`. Por enquanto tudo tranquilo. O fato é que no arquivo `envia_email1.php` os e-mails estão sendo enviados normalmente para todos os destinatários. Já o arquivo `envia_email2.php` envia somente para o destinatário do qual está servindo de base para a autenticação do SMTP. Todos os outros são ignorados.

Detalhe: os arquivos são IDÊNTICOS. Foi um Ctrl+C e Ctrl+V na cara dura. Toda a lógica de envio é semelhante, até os nomes das variáveis eu mantive.

Com base nesse impecílio, fiz o seguinte: tentei instanciar um objeto para cada email e não deu certo. Alterei a ordem de envio e não deu certo. Ao invés de passar pra variável, coloquei os emails diretamente no parâmetro em formato de string ( `$mail->addAddress('meuemail@email.com');` ) e também não deu certo.

Atualizei o pacote no PHPMailer, saindo da versão 5.2 e indo pra 6. Também não deu certo. Fiz o require da classe e depois fiz com o autoload do composer: também não deu certo rsrsrs.

De qualquer forma, o primeiro arquivo funciona normalmente, mas o segundo envia somente para o e-mail que faz a autenticação do SMTP no PHPMailer.

Venho aqui pedir-lhes socorro! A única informação que achei que talvez possa alterar em algo foi no modo DEBUG. Porém, ainda não encontrei solução a ela. Segue abaixo exemplo de como estou fazendo o disparo e, após, imagem do modo debug assim que é efetuado o disparo:

```
// Define o remetente
// =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
$mail->From = "site@dominio.com.br"; // Seu e-mail
$mail->Sender = "site@dominio.com.br"; // Seu e-mail
$mail->FromName = "Meu Site"; // Seu nome

// Define os destinatário(s)
// =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
$mail->AddAddress('destinatario1@dominio.com.br');
$mail->AddAddress('destinatario2@dominio.com.br');
$mail->AddAddress('destinatario3@dominio.com.br');
```

Segue abaixo imagem do DEBUG:

[image: DEBUG - envia_email2.php]

Enfim pessoal, ficarei grato caso algum de vocês saibam qual é o real problema disso.

Desde já agradeço!

Comment: Eles estão na mesma pasta ? Qual a hospedagem linux ou windows ? Quais as permissões do arquivo ? Eles estão até com as mesmas portas  e controles iguais ?

Comment: Sim! Tudo igual! Permissão 777 e hospedagem linux. Os dois arquivos estão na mesma pasta com tudo idêntico. É isso que está me deixando maluco. Aparentemente não há motivos pra isso não estar funcionando.

Comment: quais são as portas definidas pro envio STMP?

Comment: **$mail->From e $mail->Sender** são idênticos ao email da autenticação?

Comment: @AnthraxisBR Sobre as portas, testei todas as combinações: TLS na porta 587, porta 25, SSL na porta 465... Porta 25 não está sendo disparada, as outras duas estão fazendo o disparo normalmente. Testei nos dois casos: no arquivo 1 ele dispara pra todos os destnatários e no arquivo 2 não.

Comment: @WagnerFernandoMomesso Sim! O host, e-mail, senha e porta é o mesmo para ambos os casos.